# Is pipe or BufferedReader in java likely to loose data?

Tags: java, pipe, apache-kafka, producer-consumer

**Aim**

To read all the logs from apache server and store on s3

**Background**

We have following statement in the `httpd.conf`

`ErrorLog "| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/error_log |  /usr/bin/java -cp /usr/local/bin/CustomProducer/producer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar stdin.producer.StdInProducer /usr/local/bin/CustomProducer/Config.json >> /var/log/producer_init.log 2>&1"`

This puts the log in `error_log` file as well as on std out to be consumed by a java producer for Apache kafka

This producer eventually sends the data to kafka cluster and then amazon S3.

The `error_log` file gets rotated and then also stored on S3 using `logrotate`

**Producer Code**

```
this.stdinReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
try {
         while ((msg = this.stdinReader.readLine()) != null) {
               //Some processing which may introduce some delay
               //Send message to cluster
                this.producer.send(message); 
         }    
    }
```

**Problem**

When hourly logs are compared from kafka bucket and logrotate bucket some logs are intermittently missing without specific pattern or time.

Is it likely due to `pipe` limit or `BufferedReader` limit ? What is the way to find this out ?

Comment: Just an idea. When it comes to a normal linux pipe, the slowest pipe consumer usually blocks producer's output, which might not be the case with Apache logging subsystem as a whole and/or ErrorLog directive in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Not even slightly. The `Reader` is exactly as reliable as the underlying pipe or socket. If it's TCP it can't lose data without resetting the connection.

Comment: So what happens if there is some delay in sending the message within the loop before it can read next message. Will it have enough buffer to contain those messages ?

Comment: TCP has flow control. Ultimately the sender will stall, or be told to try again, depending on how it is written.